# (BOOL)strstr() failed in a 32-bit iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, 32-bit

i use strstr determine whether contains a string, and then use the results strongly to a BOOL type,for example:

```
BOOL result = (BOOL)strstr(aString, "test");
```

When aString contains "test" string in a 32-bit iOS device can appear sometimes the result is NO. But the strstr(aString, "test") returns the address correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the architecture, `BOOL` may be `typedef`'d to `unsigned char`. That's just 8 bits. When you cast a pointer to a `BOOL`, you may be getting just the low 8 bits from the pointer. If those bits were all 0, then the `BOOL` is false, even if the pointer was not `NULL` (0).

In other words, don't do that.

If you want a boolean value, use `strstr(aString, "test") != NULL` or even `!!strstr(aString, "test")`.

Answer (score 0):

from `man strstr`:

> RETURN VALUES:
>        If s2 is an empty string, s1 is returned; if s2 occurs nowhere in s1, NULL is returned; otherwise a pointer to the first
>        character of the first occurrence of s2 is returned.

so casting this to a `bool` is just a train wreck, it is only false when "test" is not in your test string, otherwise it will return a pointer which in a lot of architectures is larger than a bool (my system shows `sizeof(bool)==1`), so you will get a truncated answer... 
so you have a scenario where conversion to bool means that even if the answer is yes you have a 1/256 chance that it well be `false` because `bool` is only one byte

example address that would be false:

- 0x80754300
- 0x12414700
- 0xac348700
- etc. (anything that ends in 0x00)

Comment: Actually, C99's `bool` (a.k.a. `_Bool`) will safely convert all non-zero values to 1. On the architectures where Objective-C's `BOOL` is `typedef`'d to `bool`, Fly's construct is safe.

Comment: @KenThomases, you are of course correct, and I have tested that, I don't know if 32bit iOS  BOOL is or isn't typed to _Bool, but on 32 bit Mac OS X it wasn't...

Comment: `BOOL` is only typedef'd to `bool` on 64-bit iOS. The definition is in `<objc/objc.h>`.